# Not able to build QuantLib on ubuntu

Tags: c++, quantlib

Code

```
    #include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
    #include <boost/timer.hpp>
    int main ()
    {
      return 0;
    }
```

Library installation

```
sudo apt-get install libquantlib-1.1
```

QuantLib Config

```
$quantlib-config --libs
-L/usr/lib -lQuantLib
$ quantlib-config --cflags
-I/usr/include
$
```

Compile and Link step:

```
$ g++ test1.cpp -L/usr/lib -lQuantLib -I/usr/include -fPIC -o test1
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o: In function `QuantLib::CPICoupon::indexFixing() const':
test1.cpp:(.text._ZNK8QuantLib9CPICoupon11indexFixingEv[QuantLib::CPICoupon::indexFixing() const]+0x36): undefined reference to `QuantLib::CPICoupon::indexFixing(QuantLib::Date const&) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib22SwaptionVolatilityCubeE[vtable for QuantLib::SwaptionVolatilityCube]+0x100): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QuantLib::SwaptionVolatilityDiscrete::update()'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib22SwaptionVolatilityCubeE0_NS_26SwaptionVolatilityDiscreteE[vtable for QuantLib::SwaptionVolatilityCube]+0xa8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QuantLib::SwaptionVolatilityDiscrete::update()'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib22CapFloorTermVolSurfaceE[vtable for QuantLib::CapFloorTermVolSurface]+0xc8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QuantLib::CapFloorTermVolSurface::update()'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib20CapFloorTermVolCurveE[vtable for QuantLib::CapFloorTermVolCurve]+0xc8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QuantLib::CapFloorTermVolCurve::update()'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x50): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::optionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x58): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::digitalOptionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x60): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::vega(double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x68): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::density(double, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x50): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::optionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x58): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::digitalOptionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x60): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::vega(double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib20SpreadedSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::SpreadedSmileSection]+0x68): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::density(double, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib10FdmBatesOpE[vtable for QuantLib::FdmBatesOp]+0x60): undefined reference to `QuantLib::FdmBatesOp::toMatrixDecomp() const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x50): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::optionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x58): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::digitalOptionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x60): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::vega(double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x68): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::density(double, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x50): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::optionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x58): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::digitalOptionPrice(double, QuantLib::Option::Type, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x60): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::vega(double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN8QuantLib16FlatSmileSectionE0_NS_12SmileSectionE[vtable for QuantLib::FlatSmileSection]+0x68): undefined reference to `QuantLib::SmileSection::density(double, double, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib27CPICapFloorTermPriceSurfaceE[vtable for QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface]+0xb0): undefined reference to `QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface::price(QuantLib::Period const&, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib27CPICapFloorTermPriceSurfaceE[vtable for QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface]+0xb8): undefined reference to `QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface::capPrice(QuantLib::Period const&, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib27CPICapFloorTermPriceSurfaceE[vtable for QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface]+0xc0): undefined reference to `QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface::floorPrice(QuantLib::Period const&, double) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib27CPICapFloorTermPriceSurfaceE[vtable for QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface]+0x128): undefined reference to `QuantLib::CPICapFloorTermPriceSurface::cpiOptionDateFromTenor(QuantLib::Period const&) const'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib9CPICouponE[vtable for QuantLib::CPICoupon]+0x30): undefined reference to `QuantLib::CPICoupon::accept(QuantLib::AcyclicVisitor&)'
/tmp/cc0GDoC4.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8QuantLib9CPICouponE[vtable for QuantLib::CPICoupon]+0x78): undefined reference to `QuantLib::CPICoupon::checkPricerImpl(boost::shared_ptr const&) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You've installed the QuantLib 1.1 binaries through `apt-get`, but you're including the headers from a newer version (possibly one that you downloaded?)
The newer headers define more functions, which are missing from the 1.1 binary and cause the linker errors.

To avoid the errors, you need to use headers and binaries from the same version.
To use the newer one, compile and install the QuantLib binaries yourself; it should be as simple as executing:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

To use the 1.1 version instead, you need install the `dev` package which contains the headers. On my system it would be done by executing

```
sudo apt-get install libquantlib0-dev
```

but then again I have `libquantlib0` instead of `libquantlib-1.1` as you mentioned, so you better run `apt-cache search quantlib` and find out what the dev package is called.

Comment: I tried installing libquantlib0 but it is still giving me the same problem. I tried install the package manually following steps from [link] http://quantess.net/2012/09/26/quantlib-get-it-working-on-ubuntu/ but still facing the same problem. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Did you recompile your program? Also, is it possible that you're still picking up the new headers? What does `quantlib-config` say now, and what are you using?